# Setting a property to a value within a closure

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

I made a property in my view controller:

```
var cityPlaceMark = CLPlacemark()
```

And I want to assign it to a placemark in my locationManger didUpdate location function:

```
CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location, completionHandler:{(placemarks, error)->Void in
    if (error != nil) {
        println("Reverse geocode failed with error")
        return
    }

    if placemarks.count > 0 {

        //var pm = placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark

        self.cityPlaceMark = placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark
    }     
})
```

The app crashes with a Thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

If I save it in a variable declared in the closure (shown as "var pm" commented out) it works fine.

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong, and how to properly assign it to a property.
Thanks!

Comment: your `self.cityPlaceMark ` could be deallocated when you try to assign to it. Have your tried checking `self.cityPlaceMark ` e.g. a println before the assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it may be a bug.

If I make it into an optional with:

```
var cityPlaceMark: CLPlacemark?
```

and implement it in the closure:

```
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)->Void in

        if (error != nil) {
            println("Reverse geocode failed with error")
            return
        }

        if placemarks.count > 0 {

            self.cityPlaceMark = placemarks[0] as? CLPlacemark
        }
    })
```

It now works!